# Getting "Undefined reference to boost libraries" errors in Boost headers in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, boost, build, linker-errors

Boost headers in Eclipse IDE - "Undefined reference to" errors.

Hi all, I am facing this "Undefined reference to boost libraries" error within Eclipse IDE with CDT plugins installed and configured. Other programs which include pthread libraries & other C/C++ programs work fine. They build and run well.
I checked in all the links which have similar title and tried them as well, but none worked for me.

**My version of Eclipse IDE (with CDT plugin):**

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (includes Incubating components)

Version: 2022-12 (4.26.0)

Build id: 20221201-1913

OS: Linux, v.5.19.0-43-generic, x86_64 / gtk 3.24.33

Java vendor: Eclipse Adoptium

Java runtime version: 17.0.5+8

Java version: 17.0.5

**OS version: **Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Kernel Version:

```
$ uname -r
5.19.0-43-generic
```

**Boost installed location:**

```
$ whereis boost
boost: /usr/include/boost
```

This is the simple program I am trying to run. This very same program runs fine as is with in code::blocks IDE and on command prompt with g++ command.
[image: Simple c++ program with boost libraries & the error Eclipse shows after building it (on the last lines of this screenshot)]

I looked and searched for similar issues here, but none of those tried my issue. These below are the similar issue threads and the fixes/solutions what they suggested which I tried to make this work but it did not work for me and hence asking this question here.

**Try 01: including external path of boost libraries did not work**
Project -> properties -> C/C++ include Paths -> Add External Include path -> added boost libraries path (/usr/include/boost in my case) -> ok -> apply & close -> cleaned project -> build all
[image: Try 01 - including external path of boost libraries did not work]

**Try 02: Enable project specific settings in Indexer:**
Project -> properties -> C/C++ General -> Indexer -> Enable project specific settings -> checked box for Index source and Header files opened in editor -> Apply -> Apply & close -> clean -> Build all

[image: Try 02: Enable project specific settings in Indexer - did not work again]

After trying both of these above two tries, I don't have any ideas to try further. Any help here is appreciated in advance.

And finally these are the only options which are there in Project -> Properties. I don't even see any option to add any compiler specific options.
[image: No any compiler specific options to add]
I don't think I need to add any library paths as the command line to execute boost related .cpp file is `g++ -o s main.cpp` which does not need any '-l' option to link boost library.

**These are the commands my eclipse ide is using to compile and execute:**

```
g++ -c -O2   -o cppTestProj.o /home/hk/eclipse-workspace/cppTestProj/cppTestProj.cpp

g++  -o cppTestProj cppTestProj.o
```

I even tried these commands manually adding the linker option "-lboost_system", but it still doesn't work.

Awaiting on a fix of how others solved this kind of issue. Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Looks like you need to link with `libboost_chrono.so`: i.e. `-lboost_chrono` .

Comment: i don't see any option to use this linker option "-lboost_chrono" in eclipse ide.  I don't see such linker options, in Project -> Properties. Could you please let me know where do  i add this?

Comment: There is a makefile visible at the project root, so i assume that your project is using this makefile instead of eclipse build system therefore linker arguments should go into this makefile instead of property pages (Eclipse C++ project settings are actually completely missing). Also `/usr/include` is a built-in path for a stock compiler on Ubuntu so you should not add it anywhere.